# Tor and i2p tradeoffs in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor, i2p

What are the different trade-offs involved in options mentioned below that users should consider while using Tor/i2p in Bitcoin Core based on privacy and security?

1. Only Tor or i2p

   1.1 onlynet=i2p

   1.2 onlynet=onion
2. Tor/i2p and clearnet peers

   **2.1 Tor + ipv4/ipv6**

   **2.2 i2p + ipv4/ipv6**
3. Other combinations

   3.1 Tor + i2p + ipv4/ipv6

   **3.2 Tor + i2p (onlynet=onion and onlynet=i2p)**

I am not sure about using 3.1 or **3.2** which was mentioned in a [tweet thread](https://twitter.com/StopAndDecrypt/status/1366754208012189698). IMO one of them (**2.1 or 2.2**) should be used. Still doing research and looking for articles that explain trade-offs.

1.1 and 1.2 should be avoided considering the trade-offs mentioned in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21157

Comment: Not sure what this is asking. Is it asking are there downsides to using Tor, I2P, IPv4 and IPv6 all at the same time? Using all of them (or a subset) clearly offers redundancy and maximal flexibility for connecting to peers. With regards to downsides... is there a way to link IP addresses to onion addresses if they are used concurrently (privacy leak)? Other than that I can't think of any.

Comment: @MichaelFolkson Can we discuss this in chat? There are few things that I will be able to explain better

Comment: I think this question would be improved (it is a bit convoluted at the moment) if it was merely "What are the trade-offs between using Tor, using I2P or using both in Bitcoin Core?" You could do a separate question on whether using clearnet (IPv4, IPv6) in parallel impacts the usage of Tor, I2P but I suspect the answer is no (other than the obvious that when using clearnet you leak your IP address) The answer basically just answers that anyway.

Answer (score 4):

|  | Obsc location | Anon P2P | Bridge | Dissoc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Tor Only** | Yes | Yes(Tor) | Yes(Tor) | Yes |
| **i2p Only** | Yes | Yes(I2P) | No | Yes |
| **Tor+i2P** | Yes | Yes | Yes(slow) | Yes |
| **Tor+i2P+IPv4** | No | Yes | Yes(fast) | No |

[<sup>https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/o5z4r1/tor_and_i2p_tradeoffs/h2sw202?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3</sup>](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/o5z4r1/tor_and_i2p_tradeoffs/h2sw202?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Basic differences between Tor and i2p: https://github.com/prayank23/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line/blob/i2p/15_0_Using_i2p.md

> Only Tor or i2p

> Tor/i2p and clearnet peers

The `onlynet=onion` configuration option can potentially ensure the node attempts to only
connect over Tor. It is more private when you combine it with no reachable IPv4/IPv6 address,
in particular if you want to broadcast transactions without them being correlatable with your IP.

**Sybil Attacks**

On the other hand, if you only make random Tor connections, you're much more vulnerable to Sybil attacks.
As Tor addresses may be created at no cost, an attacker can potentially flood the network with many Tor
nodes and receive all of the outbound Tor connections an `onlynet=onion` node makes.

This is significantly less a concern with if you make `-addnode` connections to trusted peers
(even if they're onion addresses). It's also alleviated with IPv4/IPv6 (especially when using the -asmap
configuration option) due to the cost of obtaining IPs in many networks.

If all of your connections are controlled by a Sybil attacker, they can easily prevent you from seeing confirmed
transactions  and, with more difficulty, even trick your node into falsely reporting a transaction as confirmed
on the blockchain with most cumulative “chainwork”.

**Network Partitioning**

If too many nodes use `onlynet=onion`, it could become difficult for onion nodes to communicate with clearnet nodes,
preventing the Tor network from seeing recent transactions and blocks. It is essential that some nodes access both
clearnet and Tor.

[<sup>https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22316/commits/2c18e7f6614d665f4eb9891f83391a5317e7d113</sup>](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22316/commits/2c18e7f6614d665f4eb9891f83391a5317e7d113)

> Tor + i2p + ipv4/ipv6

If looking for privacy, this may not be the best option however I don't see any security issues with this setup.

> Tor + i2p

I would consider this as experimental for now and will update the answer if I find any issues.

**For maximum privacy, it is preferable to disable accepting incoming connections.**

Related Question: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/tor-i2p-on-a-system-and-is-i2p-better-than-tor

Comment: Thanks for this. Would I2P + Tor not offer significant extra Sybil resistance, given the attacker can't easily figure out the I2P address that belongs to a certain Onion address (and the other way around)?

Also, can you explain what exactly the "Dissoc" column is about?

Comment: Another question, do you know if it's possible to use the unofficial I2P exits (e.g., false.i2p) to connect to clearnet nodes? EDIT: Just confirmed, just HTTP, doesn't help us.

Comment: 1. Sybil attacks are possible in both Tor and I2P. Maybe i2p is more vulnerable considering less nodes. Don't think using both offers any resistance. Not sure though. 2. Don't understand how I2P address belong to onion. They are different services running on same machine for Bitcoin Core. 3. Dissoc: Disassociate anon and non-anon transactions

Comment: I'm suggesting that it's more difficult to Sybil-attack a node if that node is also getting blocks from a second network, and if it is not known which address the node has on the second network.